# Deleting a selected record in an HTML form with a checkbox

Tags: php, html, database

I have an HTML form with some records contained in it. The records should be deleted by selecting one or all records corresponding checkbox.

When I select a record's checkbox and click delete, the query runs successfully, but record does not delete.

Here is the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{ 
    $allCheckBoxId = $_POST['chkDel'];

    array_map ('mysql_real_escape_string', $allCheckBoxId);
    $ids = implode(",", $allCheckBoxId);

    $object=new connection();
    $object=$object->dbConnect();


    $st=$object->prepare(
        "delete * from banners where bannerid IN (?)");

    $st->bindParam(1, $ids);
    $delete=$st;
    $delete->execute();
    if($delete)
    {
        echo "record deleted successfully." . 
             "This will go to banners within 5 sec";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "not deleted";

    }
}
```

And HTML form:

```
<form name="myform" action="listbanners.php" method="post" OnSubmit="return onDelete();" id="frm1">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th width="13"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" title="select all" onclick="checkAll(document.myform.chkDel);" name="CheckAll" /></th>
        <th width="13">ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th><input type="submit" name="delete" value"Delete"></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $object=new connection();
        $object=$object->dbConnect();
        $st=$object->prepare("select * from banners order by bannerid desc");
        $st->execute();
        while($row=$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><input name="chkDel[]" type="checkbox" title="select" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['bannerid'];?>"/></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['bannerid'];?></td>
        <td><h3 onClick="location='editbanner.php?bannerid=<?php echo $row['bannerid'];?>'"><?php echo $row['file'];?></h3></td> 
        <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"/></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: echo out the SQL you're generating; does it work when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: i am using PDO way for communicating with mysql db. How to run that query into PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Copy the query and paste it into phpmyadmin (tab "SQL").

Answer (score 2):

```
$st=$object->prepare("delete * from banners where bannerid IN (?)");
$st->bindParam(1, $ids);
```

You're trying to bind a single parameter to an array of values. You need to pass in each value as a separate parameter; for example:

```
$st=$object->prepare("delete * from banners where bannerid IN (?,?,?)");
```

You need to include a placeholder for each value you want to include in your IN clause. You can generate the SQL dynamically, based on how many items are in `$ids`.

I missed the 'DELETE *', which is invalid syntax; but I'm leaving this in place because the point I did notice is valid. This is an incomplete answer, not a wrong one.

Comment: if i do                                                                           $st->bindParam(1,$ids);$st->bindParam(2,$ids);$st->bindParam(3,$ids); Is it correct way?

Comment: Sorry guys! this was so easy. I solved the small query problem. problem was in "delete * " and now i removed '*' and now it is working.

Comment: I should definitely have noticed that. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: I tried to answer since i am new to this site so not required reputation earned for answering self question.